# OS X: which volume is a DVD?

Tags: macos, mount, dvd

How can I programmatically determine which (if any) mounted volumes are a DVD?

I currently look for a directory with permissions 555 but I would prefer something a bit less hacky.  Thanks!!

```
$ ls -l /Volumes/
total 12
dr-xr-xr-x  4 mh    gfx    136 Aug  3  2001 DQRMX2102
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    1 Apr  6 15:09 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxrwxr-x  9 mh    gfx    374 Feb  3 12:55 data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What programming language/toolkit are you using?

If you're using Cocoa in Objective-C, you can [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-BCIDFHCF):

```
NSArray *volumes = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] mountedRemovableMedia];
```

If you want to find out from the command line or a script or something, [`diskutil`](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/diskutil.8.html) should come in handy.

```
$ diskutil info -plist /Volumes/Foobar
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
...snip...
    <key>OpticalMediaType</key>
    <string>CD-ROM</string>
...snip...
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: it might also say DVD-ROM instead

Answer (score 3):

For Cocoa, you can use NSWorkspace [mountedRemovableMedia:](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/mountedRemovableMedia) to get a list of volumes and the use NSWorkspace [getFileSystemInfo:...](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/getFileSystemInfoForPath:isRemovable:isWritable:isUnmountable:description:type:) to get more information about each mounted volume.

```
- (BOOL)getFileSystemInfoForPath:(NSString *)fullPath 
                     isRemovable:(BOOL *)removableFlag 
                      isWritable:(BOOL *)writableFlag 
                   isUnmountable:(BOOL *)unmountableFlag 
                     description:(NSString **)description 
                            type:(NSString **)fileSystemType
```

If you want to make system calls, you can use [statfs](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/statfs.2.html) at the same information.

```
int statfs(const char *path, struct statfs *buf);
```